# Java/ImageIO getting image dimensions without reading the entire file?

Tags: java, image, dimensions, javax.imageio

Is there a way to get the dimensions of an image without reading the entire file?

```
URL url=new URL(<BIG_IMAGE_URL>);
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(url);
System.out.println(img.getWidth()+" "+img.getHeight());
img=null;
```

Comment: Did you try truncating image content, just passing a small portion, say 10kb, of the image to ImageIO.read?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image height and width using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672916/how-to-get-image-height-and-width-using-java)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
try(ImageInputStream in = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(resourceFile)){
    final Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(in);
    if (readers.hasNext()) {
        ImageReader reader = readers.next();
        try {
            reader.setInput(in);
            return new Dimension(reader.getWidth(0), reader.getHeight(0));
        } finally {
            reader.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to sfussenegger for the suggestion

Comment: The code presented issues a warning in Eclipse: Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator<E> should be parameterized. Remedy options offered by Eclipse: rename in file (Ctrl+2, R direct access), Add type parameters to 'Iterator', Infer Generic Type Arguments..., Add @SuppressWarnings 'unchecked' to 'methodNameHere'. What's the syntactically correct fix for it?

Comment: Also the code snippet doesn't mention the class references needed to use the code. From Eclipse, seems to be: import javax.imageio.ImageIO; import javax.imageio.ImageReader; import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;

Comment: Thanks @David, fixed the casting issues. Those look like the right packages.

Comment: @Sam Barnum. How do you get the parameter 'resourceFile' without downloading the whole image? OP starts with an arbitrary URL, not a file.

Comment: @EL it accepts a File, readable RandomAccessFile, or InputStream

Comment: Any chance anyone could explain me the image index of `imageReader.getWidth(/*image index*/ 0 )`? Could this ever be any other value than 0? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @ClausPolanka some image file formats can contain multiple images, like GIF and multi-image JPEG

Answer (score 17):

Using [ImageReader.getHeight(int)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#getHeight(int)) and [ImageReader.getWidth(int)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#getWidth(int)) normally only reads the image header (I'm looking at JDK6 sources). So [ImageReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html) is most likely the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to look into [`ImageReader.getImageMetadata()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#getImageMetadata(int)). Unfortunately, The Java Image API is not at all easy to use.

You can find descriptions of the metadata formats in the package documentation of [`javax.imageio.metadata`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/package-summary.html).

There are third party libraries that are easier to use, such as [MediaUtil](http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/) (last updated 3 years ago, but it worked well for me).

Answer (score 0):

The solution with ImageInputStream and ImageReader is still not so efficient though because they create tmp files. It becomes much slower when image is larger or concurrency is higher, i recommend to use [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) instead.