# How can I determine the dimensions of an image file of arbitrary format (JPEG, PNG, etc.) on the JVM?

Tags: image, clojure, jvm

I'd like to go through a directory and pick out all the images and then do some things based on their dimensions.  What libraries are available for me to do this?

I'm working in Clojure but anything available on the JVM is fair game.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first person to combine the two answers below gets accepted! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(with-open [r (java.io.FileInputStream. "test.jpeg")]
  (let [image (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read r)]
    [(.getWidth image) (.getHeight image)]))
```

You can use `with-open` to have the stream closed automatically.

Here is an example of using to iterate through some number of files in a directory. It assumes all the files in the directory are images. The example directory only contains your stackoverflow avatar.

```
(defn files-in-dir [dir]
  (filter #(not (.isDirectory %))
          (.listFiles (java.io.File. dir))))

(defn figure-out-height-width
  [files]
  (map (fn [file]
         (with-open [r (java.io.FileInputStream. file)]
           (let [img (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read r)]
             [file (.getWidth img) (.getHeight img)])))
       files))

user>(figure-out-height-width (files-in-dir "/home/jmccrary/Downloads/pics/"))
([#<File /home/jmccrary/Downloads/pics/test.jpeg> 32 32])
```

Comment: That solves the heap problem but doesn't fully answer my OP. ^_^

Comment: Edited the post to show some more. Returns a sequence of vectors which you could feed to something else.

Answer (score 3):

Package [javax.io](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) is what you're looking for.

```
(import 'java.io.File)
(import 'java.io.FileInputStream)
(import 'javax.imageio.ImageIO)

(def img  (ImageIO/read (FileInputStream. (File. "myfile.png"))))

[ (.getWidth img) (.getHeight img)]
```

- Works for both png and jpg files.
- This was posted in a hurry. There are more more idiomatic ways to open a file and get an InputStream in Clojure.

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Could you provide the more idiomatic ways to accomplish this?  I'm running into Heap issues with fairly small numbers of files, I suspect because streams aren't getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more efficient answer could be

```
(ns common.image
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:import (javax.imageio ImageIO)))

(defn dimensions [src]
  (let [res (if (string? src) (io/file (io/resource src)) src)]
    (if res
      (let [image-input-stream (ImageIO/createImageInputStream res)
            readers (ImageIO/getImageReaders image-input-stream)]
        (if-let [r (and (.hasNext readers) (.next readers))]
          (try
            (.setInput r image-input-stream)
            [(.getWidth r 0) (.getHeight r 0)]
            (finally
              (.dispose r)))))
      [0 0])))
```

This doesn't require to read the whole image into memory.

Adapted from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560052

Comment: I could not get your initial version to work (https://gist.github.com/timvisher/f1a92e005fd70cdf4ece3f7bd5b0e306#file-original-version-clj). I think this is because it assumes that a string arg is a resource.

This version works (for my use case at least) https://gist.github.com/timvisher/f1a92e005fd70cdf4ece3f7bd5b0e306#file-working-version-clj