# How do I properly use this Image code?

Tags: java, image, height, width, dimension

I'm trying to get an image's Dimension online from a URL, like the person in this question:

[Java/ImageIO getting image dimensions without reading the entire file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559253/java-imageio-getting-image-dimension-without-reading-the-entire-file/1560052#1560052)

However, I don't know quite how to use the code of the best answer there to get the result. I want to get the image's height and width without having to load it.

What do I put resourceFile as, if I have a URL that goes to an image?

Comment: If it's online, you *can't* use a "resourceFile" or any file.

Comment: You can get an ImageInputStream from the static `ImageIO.createImageInputStream(InputStream is)` and you would need the InputStream from the URL for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`ImageIO.createImageInputStream(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#createImageInputStream%28java.lang.Object%29)?

> **Parameters:**
>       `input` - an `Object` to be used as an input source, such as a `File`, readable `RandomAccessFile`, or **`InputStream.`**

Further, as @Hover comments:

> ..you would need the `InputStream` from the `URL` for this.

Comment: @Hovercraft What, you mean 'read the docs.'?  (panics)  Sh*t, they're on to me!

Comment: I tried, but I'm a complete newbie at this. Thanks for your help, I got it to work after about five hours of searching for an answer!

Comment: @Michael: if you try and it doesn't work, you should show us your attempt, else how can we see what you're doing wrong.