# How can you get the pixel dimensions of a jpg in java?

Tags: java, image, file

I need to find a way to work out the length and the width of the image (which is a .jpg) I have the length of the file but it is not useful because I want to make an array to store information about each pixel of the image file I am using.

```
public void getImageData(){
    File f= new File("myPicture.jpg");
    this.length = (int) f.length();
        System.out.println("length of file = " + length);
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(f);
            } 
        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559253/java-imageio-getting-image-dimension-without-reading-the-entire-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you get the `BufferedImage`, you can just call the properties [`getWidth()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getWidth%28%29) and [`getHeight()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getHeight%28%29) on it:

```
int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If an answer works, check the green check mark next to their answer so people know you've found a solution!