# Getting a bitmap's dimensions in Android without reading the entire file

Tags: android

I would like to get a bitmap's dimensions in Android without reading the entire file.

I tried using the recommended `inJustDecodeBounds` and a custom `InputStream` that logged the `read()`s. Unfortunately based on this, the Android `BitmapFactory` appears to read a large amount of bytes.

Similar to:
[Java/ImageIO getting image dimensions without reading the entire file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559253/java-imageio-getting-image-dimension-without-reading-the-entire-file) for Android, without using ImageIO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are right to use inJustDecodeBounds. Set it to true and make sure to include Options in decode. This just reads the image size.

There is no need to read a stream. Just specify the path in the decode.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(<pathName>, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

Comment: I need to use an `InputStream` because I'm reading from the network. I want to minimize the network traffic.

`BitmapFactory` also forwards the method with a file to the stream - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#BitmapFactory.decodeFile%28java.lang.String%2Candroid.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29

Comment: @mparaz Then use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts)`. If you already have, then its likely a limitation of applying this method to a stream over a network. Aka, you may need to get the full stream over the network first before you can decode.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.URL imageUrl = new java.net.URL("https://yourUrl.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
connection.connect();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream(), null, options);
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
```