# No reader matches PNG-Stream in Java.ImageIO

Tags: java, image, png, javax.imageio

I'm trying to read the meta-data of a PNG file with java following the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560052/1141038).

But the method `ImageIO.getImageReaders(inputStream)` is returning an empty list of readers.
I assured that the stream is correct by reading it via `ImageIO.read` and rendering the resulting Image to the screen.

And this is why I'm confused: since `ImageIO.read` returns a valid image, i assume there is some `ImageReader` claiming to be able to interpret this stream. Is there a difference between interpreting image data and the meta-data of the image?

Any hints or even solutions to this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: inputStream is a InputStream or a ImageInputStream? And by "metadata " you mean things like width and height?

Comment: `inputStream` is an `InputStream` (obtained by [`java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))). And by "metadata" I mean exactly those two properties (height & width).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that [ImageIO.getImageReaders()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getImageReaders%28java.lang.Object%29) expects an `ImageInputStream`, you can try to create one from your `InputStream` using [createImageInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#createImageInputStream%28java.lang.Object%29). I guess that's what `ImageIO.read(InputStream)` does under the hood.

Anyway, if you already know that you have a PNG, why not use `getImageReadersByFormatName("png")` ?

BTW: height and width (and color model, etc) can be considered  as "image **metadata**", in the sense that they are not part of the pixels values (which would be the real data), but in common parlance, they are regarded rather as image (esential) **properties**. The image metadata is generally (and specifcally in [IIOMetadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata.html)) understood to be additional "miscelanous" data (as physical resolution, timestamp) which is normally not needed to access the image data.

Comment: This does not work for me. `getImageReadersByFormatName("png")` is not suitable here due to my actual target application. The code has to be able to read the metadata of images that are encoded in different (i.e. not only png) formats.

Comment: Silly me: I failed to update my code correctly. I was getting a reader by the help of the ImageInputStream but used my old plain InputStream as the reader's input. Now that I fixed that, it works fine! Thank you very much!!