# How to give image url to a createImageInputStream method

Tags: java, image, objectinputstream

I have an image url like,

```
String url = "http://XXXXXXX/img_High-Octane-Sauce-Company-JP5-400x1024.jpg";
```

I need this to be take as an input to the method,

```
ImageInputStream in = ImageIO.createImageInputStream( urlInputHere );
```

so I can read the width and height of the image without using image buffer.
Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

This is the way I am reading the image

```
ImageInputStream in = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(resourceFile);
try {
    final Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(in);
    if (readers.hasNext()) {
        ImageReader reader = readers.next();
        try {
            reader.setInput(in);
            return new Dimension(reader.getWidth(0), reader.getHeight(0));
        } finally {
            reader.dispose();
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (in != null) in.close();
}
```

P.S. Taken from : [Java/ImageIO getting image dimensions without reading the entire file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559253/java-imageio-getting-image-dimension-without-reading-the-entire-file)

Comment: Consider rewriting your question for clarity.

Comment: I need to read the image as the answer given in this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559253/java-imageio-getting-image-dimension-without-reading-the-entire-file

But I have only a url of the image. don't know how to use it in here

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
    String url = "http://XXXXXXX/img_High-Octane-Sauce-Company-JP5-400x1024.jpg";
    InputStream urlInputHere = new URL(url).openStream();
    ImageInputStream in = ImageIO.createImageInputStream( urlInputHere );
```