# Jsop image extract

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to get images of a web page.

Following is my code:

```
private String getImage(Document doc) {

        Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");  
        String imgUrl = "";     

        for (Element image : images) {              
            imgUrl = image.attr("abs:src");
            break;
        }       
        return imgUrl;
}
```

Here I am getting first image of page, But I need image having max height or max width in page.

I can not use attr("height") as most of images does not have height and width attribute.

Can anyone help me how can I calculate height and width of images not having attribute height and width?

Thanks

Comment: You need to get the image itself and have a look into it. A browser does the same when doing the layout and no rules for the size of an image element are given.

Comment: @Hauke can I get page logo image?

Comment: I don't understand that. Do you want to know how to get the favicon (the small icon in the URL bar, on tabs in the browser, or used for bookmarks)?

Comment: No I want to get Logo Image of url page

Comment: Your question is unclear: "I need image having max height or max width" what does this image have to do with logo? Anyway you should probably read http://stackoverflow.com/q/1559253/1393766 to see how to get width and hight of image without having to download its entire content.